# Fabric running commands on different hosts in parallel using threads

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric

I'm using fab to run commands on remote hosts. I can't use the built-in fab parallel execution mode because my code is invoked by some library which I don't have control over. It creates multiple threads and calls my **driver(host)** method with different host parameters.

Below is the code sample of how I'm trying to achieve it.

```
def setup_env_for_fab(host, user):
  env.host_string = host
  env.user = user

def run_command():
  run("python some_program.py")

def driver(host):
  setup_env_for_fab(host, "ubuntu")
  run_command()
```

So **driver(host)** function can be called by multiple threads with different host parameter. Will this run commands on different hosts parallely if **driver(host)** is called simultaneously by different threads? 
If this does not work as expected how can I achieve this?

Comment: // , You have shown us some code for a solution, but I'd like something more defined about the problem. What is the problem you are trying to solve, here, @Bourne?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't roll this by hand if you don't really need to. Fabric has the parallel execution built-in using [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), e.g. using the [`-P`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/fab.html#cmdoption-P) CLI flag:

```
$ fab -H web1,web2,web3 -P driver
```

See [Fabric docs on parallel execution](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/parallel.html) for all the options.

As for the threading support, see [FAQ - Is Fabric thread-safe?](http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html#is-fabric-thread-safe). Current Fabric 1.10 is still not thread-safe:

> **Is Fabric thread-safe?**
>
> Currently, no, it’s not – the present version of Fabric relies heavily on shared state in order to keep the codebase simple. However, there are definite plans to update its internals so that Fabric may be either threaded or otherwise parallelized so your tasks can run on multiple servers concurrently.

**Update:**

Fabric is now thread-safe: [Upgrading from 1.x](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html?highlight=thread#why-upgrade)

Comment: This doesn't help me. My code is actually invoked by some other library. I don't have control over that. It creates multiple threads and calls my code.

Comment: So My code would run into issues? Any suggestions on how I can achieve this? Any library similar to fabric I can use?

Comment: @PrathikPuthran Yes, this way you are likely to run into problems. You might try reusing just selected parts of the Fabric API, like [`fabric.network.connect`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/api/core/network.html#fabric.network.connect), if they are thread safe, or maybe drop down to [Paramiko](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.15/#), which is the underlying SSH engine for Fabric and the like.

Comment: // , If you really need a thread safe Python library for *Parallel* Shell designed that way from the ground up, consider https://libraries.io/github/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh#frequently-asked-questions.  Please feel free to contact me if you have questions about this. https://git.io/v6